# Evaluate integral with exponential and polynomial

Tags: integration

How can I show that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx=\infty
\end{align}
for $t\neq0$.

I started as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx+\int_{0}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx.
\end{align}
Here I can 'see' that the right integrand goes to infinity, and the left one would just be a real value I'd say, because the integrand goes to 0.

Is there a way for me to evaluate these integrals in a somewhat rigorous way?

Comment: It should suffice to notice that the first integral on your right-hand side has a non-negative integrand on its domain of definition, so is non-negative, while $e^{tx}/(\pi(1+x^2)) \ge x$ for large enough $x > 0$ (exponentials dominate all polynomials), so the second integral diverges to infinity.

Comment: @Mr.Chip Ohhh, of course, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $t>0$. You have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{tx}}{\pi(1+x^2)}=\infty.$$
As the integrand is positive everywhere, 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx\geq
\int_0^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx=\infty.
\end{align}
For $t<0$, you use that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{e^{tx}}{\pi(1+x^2)}=\infty,$$
and now
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx\geq
\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dx=\infty.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If the result holds for all $t > 0$, then it holds for all $t < 0$ using the $u$-substitution $u = -x$. So we can assume $t > 0$. In that case, the mean value theorem gives $e^{tx} > tx$ for all $x \ge 0$. Thus

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1 + x^2)}\, dx \ge \int_0^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\pi(1 + x^2)}\, dx > \frac{t}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1 + x^2}\, dx = \frac{t}{\pi}\lim_{b\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\log(1 + b^2) = \infty.$$